# Flask SQLAlchemy Association Table: error creating backref

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Artist model, and a Venue model, and they have a many-to-many relationship facilitated by the Show model (the shows indicate the artist, venue and date of the concert).

```
class Venue(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Venue'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='venue', lazy=True)   

class Artist(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Artist'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='artist', lazy=True)

class Show(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'Show'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Venue.id'), nullable=False)
  artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Artist.id'), nullable=False)      
  start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)    
  venue = db.relationship('Venue', back_populates='venue')
  artist = db.relationship('Artist', back_populates='artist')
```

I'd like to have a query to get the venue name, artist name, and date of all upcoming shows so had in mind the following...

```
upcoming_shows = Show.query.filter_by(show.start_time >= datetime.now()).all()
```

...so that I can then access for example, upcoming_shows[0].Venue.name, upcoming_shows[0].Artist.name and upcoming_shows[0].start_time.

That query however returns the following:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'venue' on
>   relationship 'Venue.shows': property of that name exists on mapper
>   'mapped class Show->Show'

Feel like I'm close but missing something fundamental!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I made the changes below to the code and it works now. It was rather straight-forward in the end, I simply had to ensure that the relationship names were unique :-\

```
class Venue(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Venue'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
venue_shows = db.relationship('Show', back_populates='venue', lazy=True)   

class Artist(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Artist'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
artist_shows = db.relationship('Show', back_populates='artist', lazy=True)

class Show(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'Show'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Venue.id'), nullable=False)
  artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Artist.id'), nullable=False)    

  start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

  venue = db.relationship('Venue', back_populates='venue_shows')
  artist = db.relationship('Artist', back_populates='venue_artist')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general example for what you are looking for

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```

For more details check the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)